# Full Calendar loads before the data loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

My full calendar will load then after a few seconds the data will appear. I'm loading my data with JSON.
I've tried adding a loading icon in `loading` but it shows the loading icon, then the calendar and then the data appears so it's the same issue

Any get the calendar and the data to load at the same time?

Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },

        defaultView: 'basicDay',
        allDaySlot: true,
        selectable: true,
        weekends: false,
        theme: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        eventLimitClick: 'week',
        eventTextColor: '#000000', //black
        events: '/MEO/GetCalendarEvents/',
        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            alert(calEvent.title)
        },
        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) {
                $('#loading').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        }     
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
<div id='calendar' style="width:100%"></div>
<div id="loading">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: where is id=loading in the markup? Sounds like you put it inside id=calendar

Comment: ah my mistake I added the html

Comment: if css is set to display loading over top of calendar container, it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want the calendar to appear with the data already loaded in (no empty calendar then data appears a couple of seconds later). My suggestion; get your data first and move your calendar initialization code to the callback of the function that is loading your data.

Meaning instead of passing your data in

```
events: '/MEO/GetCalendarEvents/',
```

Get the data thru a jquery ajax call, and initialize the calendar after the data has been loaded. You calendar will load with all the events on it already.